# launch or launching , how their uses are different?

Tags: gerunds

> Right before the **launch,**  engineers expressed concerns about mechanical malfunctions and advised that the **launching** be postponed.

In this sentence,  which is better and how are they different?

I wonder when there is no following object of gerund, what determines whether I use noun or gerund?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We use before most commonly with noun phrases to refer to timed events:

> I like to go for a run before breakfast.
>
> You can check in online but you have to do it at least four hours before your flight.

so its better if you say right before the launch.